# How to execute nmap from ping script

Tags: bash

I'm learning bash for pentesting, so i started with kinda usefull things for me. I created a script, thath scan whole network by my requirements. But at the end of script i want to do Nmap of this Ips.

And thats the problem, no idea how to execute it.

```
time=$(date +"%T")
ip=(192.168.0)
echo -e "Scan started at $time"
for x in $(seq 1 254); do
    ping -c 1 $ip.$x | grep "from" &
done

echo -n "Would you like to do NMAP scan (y/n)? "
read nmap
if [ "$nmap" != "${nmap#[Yy]}" ] ;then
    #here i guess have to be something
else
    #here i guess have to be something
fi
```

If user chose "y" than NMAP should scan IPs, which are pinged as live.

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Only an optimization and design hint: replace `for x in $(seq 1 254)` by `for (( x=1; x<=254; x++ ))`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution on how to use ping and nmap together

```
#!/bin/bash
ipfile=$(mktemp)               # create tmpfile for online ip's
trap 'rm -f "$ipfile"' EXIT    # rm tmpfile on exit

BASE="192.168.0"               # define your IP base

for (( i=1; i <= 254; i++ )); do
    ip="$BASE.$i"
    printf "Scanning %s " "$ip"

    # check if ip is online
    if ping -c 1 "$ip" | grep "from" >/dev/null; then
        printf "online\n"

        # write ip's into tmpfile
        printf "%s\n" "$ip" >> "$ipfile"  
    else
        printf "offline\n"
    fi
done

echo -n "Would you like to do NMAP scan (y/n)? "
read -r answer
if [ "$answer" = "y" ]; then
    # check all ip's in tmpfile with nmap
    nmap -iL "$ipfile"
fi
```